# Shipment Created but not showing under order Information Magento 2.4.2 p-2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I added a shipment information against that particular order. after added message i will check in shipment section. no shipment found on that Tab. Last week its working fine but still not able to see.
[image]

Comment: Did you reindexing after generate shipment.

Comment: check your indexing status.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Re-Index status and shipment data in `sales_shipment_grid`,

Your admin grid data would be renderer from `sales_shipment_grid` table.

First make sure that your data would be in `sales_shipment` and `sales_shipment_grid`.

If your data exist in `sales_shipment` then it would be fill in `sales_shipment_grid` after do re-indexing.

so check after reindexing.

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reset

sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @karthik if you have created shipment programmatically please check the table

```
sales_shipment
```

This table has a column order_id which hold the order id relation with **sales_order** table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've also face this issue, you can check error in log after place order and also see in below tab "comments history".
After you can `php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex` i think issue will resolve. i hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

The grid info is created via Cronjob. So, if your cronjobs are setup correctly, the shipments should appear after a few minutes.

This is the part from `vendor/magento/moidule-sales/etc/crontab.xml` which is responsable for it:

```
<job name="sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert" instance="SalesShipmentIndexGridAsyncInsertCron" method="execute">
    <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

If you want to trigger it from the command line, you can use n98-magerun2:

```
n98-magerun sys:cron:run sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert
```